# Space complexity of this monotonic algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, space-complexity

I coded an algorithm to determine if an input array is a monotonic array (its elements from left to right are entirely increasing or entirely decreasing) or not.

I was wondering what the space complexity of this algorithm is. I am thinking it is O(n) because the count increases as the size of the array increases. Basically I am increasing the count every time the current element is <= or >= to the next element. So the largest value of count and count2 would basically be the size of the input array if the loop goes through every element.

Could someone please explain and correct me if I am wrong?

```
def monotonic(array):
    count = 0
    count2 = 0
    for i in range(len(array) - 1):
        if array[i] <= array[i + 1]:
            count += 1
        if array[i] >= array[i + 1]:
            count2 += 1
    if array == []: return True
    if count == len(array) - 1 or count2 == len(array) - 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 4):

The *time* complexity is O(n).

The *space* complexity is O(1). The only storage used is for `count` and `count2`. There are no additional lists, nor are there recursive calls that would take up a variable amount of stack space.

Comment: _Technically_ space complexity is O(log n) because Python integers are unbounded :) But that only starts to matter once the input array has an unrealistic size anyway.

Comment: so using variables to hold values is always constant space?

Comment: @Thomas Two can play that game! *Technically* lists can only be so big, probably O(2^64) upper bound at a guess, and hence the counts will cap out around 2^64.

Comment: @SamuelP Correct. For all practical purposes integer variables have a constant size.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: for guys dealing with number theory, I am not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

When counting size complexities, the usual assumption is that if something fits in memory, then its size fits into a constant number of bits, because the size of a computer's machine word is a constant defined by its architecture.

This is a *pragmatic* choice, and we make different assumptions when it's appropriate.  The goal when making a statement of complexity is to say something *useful*.  We all know that asymptotic analysis doesn't technically apply to real, bounded, machines, but it's a useful tool anyway.